# How to add multiple github repos to trigger a jenkins build?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have 3 github repos and my build need to include all of them. How can I configure a free style project on Jenkins to listen on more than one github repo commit? I want to trigger the project on any commit to any of these three repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot do that in the same Job. If u want three separate repos to be monitored then u have to have three separate Free style projects.

In case there are three branches then we can monitor them. Let me know if you would like to know more.

Comment: I have three repos, UI, Backend and Release. UI and Backend are upstreams while Release is the downstream repo. I want to combine them into one pipeline view. But the pipeline view doesn't support two initial jobs. That's why I want to create one project to monitor all these three repos. Do you have any idae on how to achieve this?

Comment: I think we can achieve this using Pipeline jobs, but its gonna be hell lot of work and not easy to maintain as well. Let me see if I can helo you out, but as of now nothing is in my mind.